# Database Design - Drop Down Input Box Issue

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm trying to create a friendship site. The issue I'm having is when a user joins a website they have to fill out a form. This form has many fixed drop down items the user must fill out. Here is an example of one of the drop downs.

**Drop Down (Favorite Pets)**

Items in Favorite Pets

```
 1. Dog
 2. Cat
 3. Bird
 4. Hampster
```

What is the best way to store this info in a database. Right now the profile table has a column for each fixed drop down. Is this correct database design. See Example:

```
User ID | Age | Country       | Favorite Pet | Favorite Season 
--------------------------------------------------------------
   1    | 29  | United States | Bird         | Summer
```

Is this the correct database design? right now I have probably 30 + columns. Most of the columns are fixed because they are drop down and the user has to pick one of the options.

Whats the correct approach to this problem?

**p.s.** I also thought about creating a table for each drop down but this would really complex the queries and lead to lots of tables.

Another approach

`Profile` table

```
ID | username | age
-------------------
1  | jason    |  27
```

`profileDropDown` table:

```
ID | userID | dropdownID
------------------------
 1 |   1    |      2
 2 |   1    |      7
```

Drop Down table:

```
ID | dropdown | option
---------------------
 1 | pet      | bird
 2 | pet      | cat
 3 | pet      | dog
 4 | pet      | Hampster
 5 | season   | Winter
 6 | Season   | Summer
 7 | Season   | Fall
 8 | Season   | spring
```

Comment: Yes each list table should be separate table, unless you are storing the text (i.e. DOG instead of 1) which is bad design. Having 30+ columns is not a problem, but do they make sense in being together, DB101 - Read about Normalizing your database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Best way to approach" or "correct way" will open up a lot of discussion here, which risks this question being closed. I would recommend creating a drop down table that has a column called "TYPE" or "NAME". You would then put a unique identifier of the drop down in that column to identify that set. Then have another column called "VALUE" that holds the drop down value.

For example:

```
ID |  TYPE  | VALUE
1  | PET    | BIRD
2  | PET    | DOG
3  | PET    | FISH
4  | SEASON | FALL
5  | SEASON | WINTER
6  | SEASON | SPRING
7  | SEASON | SUMMER
```

Then to get your PET drop down, you just select all from this table where type = 'PET'

Comment: thanks for your response :). What about the user table would you leave it with 30 + columns.

Comment: Without knowing more about your table design, it's hard to say. You could have "PET_DROPDOWN_ID" on the user table and use the ID from the drop down table that they selected here. You could create a relationship mapping table that has the selected drop downs in it. It's really hard to pick without knowing all the rest of the design.

Comment: Ive just started this database, So right now all i have is a user table. I was thinking a relationship mapping table.

Comment: I personally like the relationship mapping table approach :-)

Answer (score 0):

Will the set of questions (dropdowns) to be asked every user ever be changed? Will you (or your successor) ever need to add or remove questions over time? If no, then a table for users with one column per question is fine, but if yes, it gets complex.

Database purists would require two tables for each question:

- One table containing a list of all valid answers for that question
- One table containing the many to many relation between user and answer to “this” question

If a new question is added, create new tables; if a question is removed, drop those tables (and, of course, adjust all your code. Ugh.) This would work, but it's hardly efficient.

If, as seems likely, all the questions and answer sets are similar, then a three-table model suggests itself:

- A table with one row per question (QuestionId, QuestionText)
- A table with one row for each answer for each Question (QuestionId, AnswerId, AnswerText)
- A table with one row for each user-answered question (UserId, QuestionId, AnswerId)

Adding and removing questions is straightforward, as is identifying skipped or unanswered questions (such as, if you add a new question a month after going live).

As with most everything, there’s a whole lot of “it depends” behind this, most of which depends on what you want your system to do.